# Copy values from one observation to another based on unique identifier

Tags: replace, stata, stata-macros

I have a dataset with many variables. For a number of observations I want to replace their values (in a large number of variables) with the values of another observation (for the same variables) based on a unique identifier. The unique identifier is not equal to the Stata observation numbers (_n).

This is similar to several other threads, but as far as I can tell, their solutions are not fully transferrable

1. [transfer values from one variable to another in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591077/transfer-values-from-one-variable-to-another-in-stata) But I have no simple lexical relationship
   that I could use
2. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-06/msg00056.html But I can't rely on the Stata observation numbers, because the dataset is dynamic and the order and number of observations may change.

Here is a piece of code based on the solution from the second link but adjusted to my problem (I changed the content of the square bracket in the last macro). I am aware that this code does not work because the square bracket here could only contain a Stata obs number (_n). But I think this should illustrate well, what I am trying to achieve:

In this example, I would like to replace the values of the observations whose unique_id is 25 and 38 with the values of the observation whose unique_id is 21. This should be done for all variables in my local varlist.

```
set obs 50

local vlist v1 v2 v3 v4 v5

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate `v' = runiform()
}

gen unique_id=_n+20  // this is just to illustrate that the unique_id is not equal to _n


foreach var of local vlist {
replace `var' =`var'[unique_id==21] if unique_id==25 | unique_id==38
}
```

Comment: That syntax is legal but not what you want usually. `unique_id == 21` is evaluated as 1 if true and 0 if false. A reference to varname`[1]` will be what you want if and only if the data have been sorted previously so that `unique_id` is 21 in the first observation, so that subscript is correct. Otherwise put, Stata is not R in this respect! The syntax used is not a way to select a scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
foreach var of local vlist {
    su `var' if unique_id == 21, meanonly 
    replace `var' = r(mean) if unique_id==25 | unique_id==38
}
```

And here is another way to do it:

```
gen reference = unique_id == 21 
sort reference 

foreach var of local vlist {
    replace `var' = `var'[_N] if unique_id==25 | unique_id==38
}
```

Of course if you looked at the data and worked out that at the moment identifier 21 is in observation 42, say, then using that as subscript that is a direct answer, but not good or robust style.

See also [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055) for a review of some techniques in this territory.

I'd sympathise with anyone who thought that Stata style looks awkward for this problem. Also, this kind of question seems terribly *ad hoc*, but then problems like this are real too.

Comment: Thanks so much, Nick! The second one of your solutions worked like a charm! Your first solution gave me a type mismatch error - I have yet to figure out why (my actual unique identifier variable is a numeric float variable just like in the example above and in my understanding it should not make a difference, what the data type of the vars in vlist v1-v5 is?). Probably you would need more info on my data to answer this one, but since the second alternative worked, I leave it at this. Also, that paper seems very useful, also to some colleagues who work on panel data a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: Your question code _creates_ `v1` to `v5` as numeric. But if any of your actual variables is string, `summarize` won't barf but the mean is returned as missing and you can't `replace` any of its values by system missing, which is a numeric value.  So, the code for the first solution depends on your question code, while the second solution is more general. Glad it helped.

Comment: "returned as missing" is not quite right. But after  `summarize` of a string variable if you attempt to use `r(mean)` it is evaluated as numeric system missing any way.